# How to change a Html text color dynamically in Objective C

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I have a html page, My requirement is in my Objective C code I need to find a text for example in the below example I have "Color Change" in `<p>` tag, Once I find the text, I need to change the `<p>` tag color value, How can we achieve it.

```
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body>
> 
> <h1 style="color:blue;">This is a heading</h1> <p
> style="color:red;">Color Change</p>
> 
> </body> </html>
```

Comment: so you want in webview?

Comment: Any where is fine, I want to change the HTML and display it

Answer (score 0):

if you are using local html file

then this code might be helpful for you..

```html
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"];

NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",htmlFile);

NSLog(@"Hello");

[self._webview  loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body bgcolor=\"#000000\" text=\"#FFFFFF\" face=\"Bookman Old Style, Book Antiqua, Garamond\" size=\"5\">%@</body></html>", text] baseURL: nil];
```

here in the below code  color:#fff tag use for text color #fff use black color

```html
NSString *webStr =@"Your text use";

[self._webview  loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div id ='foo' align='left' style='line-height:18px; float:left;width:300px; font-size:13px;font-family:helvetica;background-color:transparent; color:#fff;>%@<div>",webStr] baseURL:nil];
```

let me know , is this helpful or not for you

Comment: Thans for the reply, Actually in Runtime i will get the @"Your text use", By using it i need to search in which tag the text is there (I have thousands of lines). After finding the Tag (Which has the text), then i need to Change the tag properties

Answer (score 0):

In the end, setTextColor: is the answer, there's an important detail missing from the earlier answers: To get this to work in iOS 8, I had to set the color =after= I set the text.

```html
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _myTextView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _myTextView.text   = @"hai hello hello..."
```